# Only allow fixed number of random points in each tile

Tags: matlab

Following up on a previous question, I have code that I think should limit the number of randomly generated points in each quadrant of the total tile; however, it is not working.

```
n = 4;
used = [];
k = 0;
a1_count = 0;
a2_count = 0;
a3_count = 0;
a4_count = 0;
min = 1;
max = 1;

while k<n
    x = rand*2;
    y = rand*2;

    notvalid = 0;

    if (0 <= x) && (x <= 1) && (0 <= y) && (y <= 1)
        a1_count = a1_count + 1;
    end
    if (1 < x) && (x <= 2) && (0 <= y) && (y <= 1)
        a2_count = a2_count + 1;
    end
    if (0 <= x) && (x <= 1) && (1 < y) && (y <= 2)
        a3_count = a3_count + 1;
    end
    if (1 < x) && (x <= 2) && (1 < y) && (y <= 2)
        a4_count = a4_count + 1;
    end
    %%%
    if (min <= a1_count) && (a1_count <= max) && (min <= a2_count) && (a2_count <= max)...
            && (min <= a3_count) && (a3_count <= max) && (min <= a4_count) && (a4_count <= max)
        notvalid=1;
    end

    if notvalid
        continue
    end

    used(end+1,:) = [x;y];
    k = k+1;


end
```

I wish to generate 4 random points, and have one in each quadrant of the total area. To do this, I have a maximum and minimum number of points in each quadrant (in this case 1), and an if statement to check that the count for each tile falls within the min and max. If it doesn't, then `notvalid = 0` and the loop should begin again. This function doesn't seem to work however, as the loop finishes with 4 points total and is completely random (all the counts should = 1).

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the previous question that you are following on from? Ideally each question you ask should be self-contained, so if you could add a bit of background information it would be appreciated.

Comment: The previous question was just involving the code you see but with a syntax error which I adjusted for

Comment: As a side note don't use `min` and `max` as variable names since those are built-in functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but the easiest approach would probably be something like

1. Select `N` random numbers within the x/y range of the first grid cell
2. Repeat for all grid cells

Here is some basic code that should create `N` random x/y points per grid cell

```
% Define the grid (for demonstration purposes)
dx = 1; dy = 1;
xrange = 0:dx:2;
yrange = 0:dy:2;

% Number of points per cell
N = 1;

[lowerx, lowery] = meshgrid(xrange(1:end-1), yrange(1:end-1));

% Store all those random numbers in a cell
data = cell(size(lowerx));

for k = 1:numel(lowerx);
    % Generate 4 random points within the x/y range
    xcoord = (rand(N, 1) * dx) + lowerx(k);
    ycoord = (rand(N, 1) * dy) + lowery(k);

    data{k} = [xcoord, ycoord];
end

disp(data)

data =

    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
```

**EDIT**

To address your question *directly* using the code that you have provided, the logic in the code in your question is a little wonky. I have rewritten your while loop to be a little clearer so we can talk through it.

```
while k < n
    x = rand * 2;
    y = rand * 2;

    if y >= 0 && y < 1
        if x >= 0 && x < 1
            a1_count = a1_count + 1;
        else
            a2_count = a2_count + 1;
        end
    else
        if x >= 0 && x < 1
            a3_count = a3_count + 1;
        else
            a4_count = a4_count + 1;
        end
    end

    counts = [a1_count, a2_count, a3_count, a4_count];
    notValid = all(counts >= minimum) && all(counts <= maximum);

    if notValid
        continue;
    end

    used(end+1,:) = [x;y];
    k = k+1;
end
```

So the biggest thing is your `notValid` check. If you actually look at what you're checking (that all your `*_count` variables are within the pre-specified limits), I believe that if all of those conditions are true, then the current point *is* valid; however you state just the opposite.

Then you basically say, that if the current `x` `y` *is* valid, then add it to the `used` list. Well this logic is fine except that you define validity backwards as I stated before.

Ok so that aside, let's look at when you think that a point is *not* valid. Well, then you (correctly) go to the next iteration, but **you never decrement the `*_count` variable**. So say you had 1 point in quadrant 1 already and the second iteration through the loop it's in quadrant 1 again. Well you'd add 1 to `a1_count` and then see that it isn't valid (`a1_count` exceeds `max`) and go to the next loop, but `a1_count` *stays* at 2 despite really only having 1 because you just rejected it.

Now, all of that aside. Let's consider the *first* time through your loop and look at your validity check. Since you only add *one* point. Your validity check can **never** pass (if implemented correctly) because *all* `*_count` variables except the one that was just incremented will be less than the min.

So I think what happened is you probably did the validity check correctly at first, ended up with an infite while loop, and then negated that check, didn't get an infinite loop, but as a result got an incorrect solution.

The solution that you are getting currently, is literally the first 4 times through the while loop due to the incorrect logic.

If you really like your current approach, we can clean up the code to be correct.

```
n = 4;
used = zeros(0,2);
minimum = 1;
maximum = 1;

counts = [0 0 0 0];

while true
    x = rand * 2;
    y = rand * 2;

    if y >= 0 && y < 1
        if x >= 0 && x < 1
            quadrant = 1;
        else
            quadrant = 2;
        end
    else
        if x >= 0 && x < 1
            quadrant = 3;
        else
            quadrant = 4;
        end
    end

    % Check to see if we can even add this point
    if counts(quadrant) + 1 > maximum
        continue;
    end

    counts(quadrant) = counts(quadrant) + 1;
    used = cat(1, used, [x, y]);

    isComplete = all(counts >= minimum & counts <= maximum) && ...
                 size(used, 1) == n;

    if isComplete
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot create the grid first  as I would like to have a prior checking function as well. This would be to ensure that the distance between the points is not too close. Ideally I would have: 1. Generate random coordinates, 2. Check the coordinates are not too close to other generated coordinates - if they are go back to (1), if not proceed, 3. Check there are the correct number of random generated points in each tile of the grid

Comment: @Steezer I'm confused though. In your initial code you literally loop until you have one point in each quadrant (which you know the grid points). With my approach, you create `n` points per grid cell. I'm not sure where the difference is. I just manually created the grid for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @Steezer updated my answer to go through in detail what was wrong with your logic, offered up a variant of your solution, and then kept the last part in there as I think that it is the clearest and easiest solution.

Comment: thanks for walking me through this. I am not getting the expected results though using the last section of code you posted. It runs fine for putting 1 point in each quadrant, however if I say wanted a minimum of 0 and maximum of 2 I only get one point out. If i also increase n, then I get strange numbers of x and y coordinates in the used file.

Comment: @Steezer Using a minimum of 0 *would* result in only getting one point out since all counts satisfy the criteria on the first pass (all are >= min and <= max)

Comment: @Steezer Oh wait I see what you mean. I updated the code because you want to ensure that you have `n` points.